# 'Considered as refugee' or 'considered a refugee'

Tags: sentence-construction, indefinite-article, singular-vs-plural

I was recently marked down for the following sentence in an essay:

> While the majority of boat arrivals meet the requirements under the United Nations Refugee Convention to be considered **a** genuine refugee, it should be noted that not everyone is fleeing persecution.

The person who marked the paper corrected the first part of the sentence and marked me down, stating that it should say:

> While the majority of boat arrivals meet the requirements under the United Nations Refugee Convention to be considered **as** genuine refugee...

So my question is, which is correct?

Comment: Did he correct it to "considered as genuine refugee" or "considered as genuine refugee**s**"?

Comment: He only corrected the 'AS' (considered as genuine refugee'). It would make more sense if he added an 's' after refugees...

Comment: Then he should not be correcting your writing. Err, rather, wrecking it.

Comment: hahah I know. I'm submitting a grade appeal :)  He has been pretty aggressive towards me because I corrected his English a few times. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy in thinking it doesn't make sense.